# How to create a filled arrow CustomLineCap?

Tags: c++, gdi+

The MSDN documentation has several open arrow examples but no examples for filled arrows.

I just want to create a bigger arrow than the default LineCapArrowAnchor. I tried several things and can't get it to work. It should be simple, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Looks like there's an **AdjustableArrowCap** class that derives from CustomLineCap and does just what I wanted.